# join row as coloumn for tax

Tags: php, mysql

I Have two tables in mysql database. One is tax rates where tax field are created like 5% , 10% (Max 5 row is in tax table). And another table is sales_item which contain the products with tax_rate_id field (related to tax id) . Now the last table is sales which have the bill_id of products.

Sales table :

```
+--------+------+---------------+-----------+-------
| id     |Name  | Service tax   | Table tax | Total|
+--------+------+---------------+-----------+-------
|     42 |   A  |    10         |    2      |  50  |
|     41 |   B  |    20         |    3      |  60  |
+--------+------+----------------+----------+------+
```

Tax table:

```
+--------+----------+-----------+
| id     | name     | itemvalue |
+--------+----------+-----------+
|      1 | VAT A%   |        10 |
|      2 | VAT B%   |         3 |
|      3 | VAT C%   |         9 |
|      4 | VAT D%   |        40 |
|      5 | VAT E%   |        40 |
+--------+----------+-----------+
```

sales_item table :

```
+--------+---------+------+------ -+
| id     | saleid  | Price| tax_id | 
+--------+---------+---------------+
|      1 |   42    | 1    |  1     |
|      2 |   42    | 2    |  2     |
+--------+---------+------+--------+
```

I want output like this....
Output:

```
+--------+--------------------+----------+-----+----+--------------+
| id     |No of prdct A% tax  | B% Tax   | C%  | D% | E% | Serv Tax|
+--------+----------------------+--------+----------+----+----------
|     42 |       1            |    1     |  0  | 0  | 0  |  10     |
+--------+------+-------------+----------+-----+-------------------+
```

so how is it possible to show this type of output in mysql query. Please find my database schema and do the needfull pls help :[pastebin](http://pastebin.com/n32yxdKr)

Comment: I'm under the impression you are looking to use some sort of joins statement. Can you refreeze how you want your output to look. field.table |field.table  | field.table   | field.table  | field.table | field.table. This way it will be clear what fields and from what table you want the output to come from.

Comment: i want sale.id | tax.field1 | tax.field2 | tax.field3 | tax.field4 | tax.field5 | sale.table_tax | sale.total . 
How many product has been sold for tax.field 
 42(sale_id) |     1(one product)     |    1(one product)      |  0(0 product)   | 0  | 0  |  10

Comment: there is only 3 fields in your tax table. How can you have field4 and field5?

Comment: I want to convert tax table row to coloumn like...
VAT A% | VAT B% |  VAT C% | VAT D% |  VAT E% then join with sale_item table to find the tax_id  and calculate how many product with tax_id 1. like in my sales_item there is two product with tax_id 1,2 and the 1(VAT A%) or 2(VAT B%) related to tax_table..

Comment: You're confusing issues of data retrieval with those of data display. The latter is best handled in the presentation layer / application level code (php in this case)

Answer (score 1):

I have done this query like this..

```
SELECT  s.reference_no as rno , a.id, a.product_name, a.sale_id, s.id as sale,
        count(CASE WHEN b.id = 1 THEN b.name ELSE NULL END) as tax1,
        Count(CASE WHEN b.id = 2 THEN b.name ELSE NULL END) tax2,
        Count(CASE WHEN b.id = 3 THEN b.name ELSE NULL END) tax3,
        Count(CASE WHEN b.id = 4 THEN b.name ELSE NULL END) tax4,
        Count(CASE WHEN b.id = 5 THEN b.name ELSE NULL END) tax5,

       sum(CASE WHEN b.id = 1 THEN a.val_tax ELSE NULL END) sum1,
       sum(CASE WHEN b.id = 2 THEN a.val_tax ELSE NULL END) sum2,
       sum(CASE WHEN b.id = 3 THEN a.val_tax ELSE NULL END) sum3,
       sum(CASE WHEN b.id = 4 THEN a.val_tax ELSE NULL END) sum4,
       sum(CASE WHEN b.id = 5 THEN a.val_tax ELSE NULL END) sum5

FROM    sale_items a
        INNER JOIN tax_rates b
            ON a.tax_rate_id = b.id
         JOIN sales s ON s.id = a.sale_id   
GROUP   BY s.id
order BY sale desc
```

Comment: when i try to sum of sum1+sum2+sum3+sum4+sum5 as total_sum occured an error that Unknown column 'total_tax_sum1' in 'field list' . So how to sum of alias fields